# ValueHelpDialog error adding element with duplicate id

Tags: sapui5

The first time I open die ValueHelpDialog and chose an item there are no errors. However when I open the dialog again and click on the same entry I get the following error:

> Uncaught Error: Error: adding element with duplicate id
>   'EQ5IPAKCZJMZR'
>       at constructor.x.registerElement (Core-dbg.js:2711)...

When I click again i get another error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getKey' of undefined
>       at constructor.onVHOK (ValueHelper.js?eval:35)...

When I click a third time it works without an error.

I use

```
this._dialog.close();
this._dialog.destroy();
```

in the event handlers for the ok event as well as for the cancel event.

Is the second error related to the first one? I thought closing and destroying the dialog would be enough to avoid those duplicate id errors.

Edit: More code
Controller:

```
this._ValueHelper = new ValueHelper();

/* Calling valueHelper */
onVH: function(oEvent) {
            this._ValueHelper.handleValueHelp(this, {
                srcCtrl: oEvent.getSource()
            });
        },
```

ValueHelper.js:

```
handleValueHelp: function(oController, mOptions) {
            if (mOptions == null) {
                mOptions = {};
            }

            this._controller = oController;
            this._view = oController.getView();
            this._model = this._controller.getModel();
            this._callback = mOptions.fnCallback;
            this._srcCtrl = mOptions.srcCtrl;
            if (this._dialog != null) {
                this._dialog.open();
            } else {
                this._buildValueHelp();
            }
        },

_buildValueHelp: function() {
            var oDialog = sap.ui.xmlfragment(
                "xxx.view.fragments.valueHelper.ValueHelp",
                this
            );
            this._view.addDependent(oDialog);
            this._dialog = oDialog;

            this._registerEnterEvent(oDialog);
            var oTable = sap.ui.xmlfragment(
                "xxx.view.fragments.valueHelper.ValueHelpTable",
                this
            );
            this._table = oTable;
            oDialog.setTable(oTable);
            oDialog.open();
        },

onVHOK: function(oEvent) {
            var sId = oEvent.getParameter("tokens")[0].getKey();

            this._handleOk(sId);

            this._dialog.close();
            /*this._dialog.destroy();*/
        },

onVHClose: function() {
            this._dialog.close();
            /*this._dialog.destroy();*/
        },
```

ValueHelp.fragment:

```
<core:FragmentDefinition xmlns="sap.m" xmlns:core="sap.ui.core" xmlns:vh="sap.ui.comp.valuehelpdialog" xmlns:fb="sap.ui.comp.filterbar">
    <vh:ValueHelpDialog  key="id" ok="onVHOK" cancel="onVHClose" selectionChange="onVHSelectionChange"
        title="Car" supportMultiselect="false" supportRanges="false" supportRangesOnly="false" descriptionKey="Car">
        <vh:filterBar>
            <fb:FilterBar advancedMode="true" filterBarExpanded="true" search="onVHShipSearch">
                <fb:filterGroupItems>
                    <fb:FilterGroupItem groupName="car" name="n1" label="Name">
                        <fb:control>
                            <Input  />
                        </fb:control>
                    </fb:FilterGroupItem>
                    <fb:FilterGroupItem groupName="car" name="n2" label="imnr">
                        <fb:control>
                            <Input/>
                        </fb:control>
                    </fb:FilterGroupItem>
                </fb:filterGroupItems>
            </fb:FilterBar>
        </vh:filterBar>
    </vh:ValueHelpDialog>
</core:FragmentDefinition>
```

ValueHelpTable.fragment:

```
<core:FragmentDefinition xmlns="sap.m" xmlns:core="sap.ui.core" xmlns:t="sap.ui.table">
    <t:Table rows="{path: '/Cars'}"  selectionBehavior="Row" selectionMode="Single">
        <t:columns>
            <t:Column>
                <t:label>
                    <Label text="Number"/>
                </t:label>
                <t:template>
                    <Text text="{ path: 'number', formatter: '.formatter.leadingZeroes' }"/>
                </t:template>
            </t:Column>         
            <t:Column>
                <t:label>
                    <Label text="Name"/>
                </t:label>
                <t:template>
                    <Text text="{name}"/>
                </t:template>
            </t:Column>
            <t:Column>
                <t:label>
                    <Label text="imnr"/>
                </t:label>
                <t:template>
                    <Text text="{imnr}"/>
                </t:template>
            </t:Column>
        </t:columns>
    </t:Table>
</core:FragmentDefinition>
```

Answer (score 1):

> I thought closing and destroying the dialog would be enough to avoid those duplicate id errors.

Usually, it is. But the dialog is probably still being referenced by other elements. In this case, you could...:

- Try to remove the references from all reference holders before destroying it.
  **For example**, if the view has the dialog in its `<dependents>` aggregation:

  ```js
  this._dialog.attachEventOnce("afterClose", () => {
    this.getView().removeDependent(this._dialog);
    this._dialog.destroy();
    this._dialog = null;
  }).close();
  ```

  But I'm not aware of any effective ways to find all reference holders. Hence ..
- Double check if it's really necessary to destroy the dialog every time after closing. Such an attempt is usually a sign of *premature optimization*. As long as there is no memory issue, I'd keep the dialog in memory so that it can be opened quickly next time.

If you're destroying the dialog for another reason, please add it to your question.

Comment: I destroyed the dialog because i assigned an id to the table of my valuehelper. But i already tried it without destroying the dialog after close/ok, still get the same error. I even debugged the whole ValueHelper Control to find the error but didnt find anything. Thanks for the advice regarding the destroying of dialogs, i will keep that in mind!

Comment: @NJW Are you actually creating the dialog every time when the dialog should be opened? It would be nice if more code is added to your question with which we can reproduce the behavior.

Comment: I added more code, i hope it helps to understand my problem. As to your question, since i dont destroy the dialog anymore, i only create the dialog it wasnt opened yet(visible in my added code)

Comment: @NJW Thank you. Can you also attach the code from the two fragments `ValueHelpTable` and `ValueHelp`? And what did you mean exactly by "However when I [...] click on the same entry" --> What is an entry in this context?

Comment: Added code of the two fragments. An entry for example is a single car object or oData Entity(not sure if thats correct)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and resolved it by making this sequence of choices.

```
    closeIndicator: function(oEvent) {
        this._dialog.close();  // First: close fragment
        this._dialog.destroy();  //Second: destoy fragment 
        this._dialog=null;  // Third: null name/pointer 
    },
```

The problem is that when you perform the destroy you do not nullify the variable.

Comment: i tried this approach but didnt work in my case. But i head a colleague of mine doesnt have this problem in a similar app. I will try to get his coding and see if it helps with my problem

Comment: What is the error that the system gives you with this approach? Check if that variable also you use them for another fragment

Comment: its actually the same error as before. No other fragments using that variable.

Comment: Then you are using that variable in another process, or you may also not void the variable when you close the fragment